# Images Merging in flutter

Tags: image, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Is there a way to merge multiple images to a single image. I have seen merge_image library but it didn't worked. can anyone help with it. All i have is list of image file which I need to merge it as single.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [image_editor](https://pub.dev/packages/image_editor)

```
  final slideLength = 180.0;
final option = ImageMergeOption(
  canvasSize: Size(slideLength * count, slideLength * count),
  format: OutputFormat.png(),
);

final memory = await loadFromAsset(R.ASSETS_ICON_PNG);
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  option.addImage(
    MergeImageConfig(
      image: MemoryImageSource(memory),
      position: ImagePosition(
        Offset(slideLength * i, slideLength * i),
        Size.square(slideLength),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  option.addImage(
    MergeImageConfig(
      image: MemoryImageSource(memory),
      position: ImagePosition(
        Offset(
            slideLength * count - slideLength * (i + 1), slideLength * i),
        Size.square(slideLength),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

final result = await ImageMerger.mergeToMemory(option: option);
provider = MemoryImage(result);
setState(() {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stack images vertically

```
  Image stackImagesVertically(List<Image> images) {
    int singleWidth = images[0].width;
    int singleHeight = images[0].height;

    Image stackedImage = Image(singleWidth, singleHeight * images.length);

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
      copyInto(stackedImage, images[i], dstY: i * singleHeight);
    }

    return stackedImage;
  }
```

Comment: Can you add the reference of `copyInto `?

Comment: @PalkeshJain it comes from the Images package. Import it and you will we able to use it